# Keras Init Sequential model layers by Model layers

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, keras-layer

I'm trying to build some app using Transfer Learning. I want to use Vgg16 so I've done sth like this:
`vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()` but I want to transfer layers from Vgg16 to my model.
`model = Sequential(layers=vgg16_model.layers)` (I've seen this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDHpqu52soI&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL&index=13))
but it leads me to error

> TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found:
>    tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer

How can I init my Sequential model by vgg16 layers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think its better and easier to use the functional API for this, check https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

Comment: I'll try that but I just wonder why it works on this tutorial

Comment: I figured out why it works on tutorial and didn't work in my case. The reason of this situation was import section. I was imported tensorflow.keras instead of keras.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vgg = VGG16()

model = Sequential()
model.add(vgg)
model.add(...) # add additional layers
```

Comment: This causes error:  > TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model>